# How I make Windows 7+ share a partition without asking passwords, homegroup, etc...?

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-8, windows-10, network-shares

I have a kinda messy network, that also has heavily mixed-OS (there are XP, Win7, Win8, Win10, server-Linux, desktop-Linux, OSX, Androids, Smart TV, iOS...)

I can't figure how to make Win7 and beyond share some partitions easily.

I want to do something like I could in Win98, right-click some partition, tell that it is public, and then mess with it from any device in the network that had some kind of SMB driver.

I tried disabling homegroups, enabling homegroups, all troubleshooters, disabling homegroups again, setting everyone to the same "WORKGROUP", use the network settings on the loosest security I could (disable passwords, allow read/write for "everyone", use lowest bit encryption...), and the thing still doesn't work, machines randomly don't see each other when they are some kind of new Windows (while OSX for example see all machines always), and trying to connect to Windows machines, doesn't matter if I am using the name or a manually input IP, it keeps asking for password, and no matter what I try, it is always wrong, I even tried settings several machiens to have the same username and password for administrator and accessing them from each other, it didn't worked.

EDIT: To make clear, the question is about how to tell Win7, and if possible newer ones, to share something and not ask password, nor a homegroup. The important clients for this currently are other Windows machines. I mention other OSes because whatever I do can't break them (homegroups for example seemly break other OS networking systems).

Comment: Can your question be a little more specific? I realize you have a complex network, but we need to distill your question down to something people can actually you with. For example, we can keep your question to say two machines? What OS is the server (with the partition you want to share), what OS is the client? Are they on the same network and what filesystem are you using to try to connect the two (SMB)? Right now, you've included a lot of good details, but not how to specifically help you. You can later search and/or post multiple questions to address different server/client configurations.

Comment: fixed, I guess?

Comment: Thanks, your question is more specific for Win7 to other Win7 machines I guess. I can only say if File & Print Sharing is not working, perhaps it is a firewall on the router level, or on each workstation level. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731402%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 - I'd try experimenting with starting file sharing on one workstation, then try on a different one. All my laptops see each other fine on Windows 7 since they are all on the same switch and local network.

Comment: Sometimes when want to connect to another computer, your login has to be domain style where your enter the computers name back slash administrator. If computer name is speeder, then login is speeder\administrator

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming by partition you mean folder.

You need to do two things:

Disable password protected sharing: Control Panel > Network and Sharing Center > Advanced Sharing Settings > Select the firewall profile you are currently using and then select "Disable password protected sharing".

The next thing is to add the "Everyone" group to the NTFS and share permissions of the folder.

Comment: partition I mean... partition. not folder.

Comment: Also, I wrote on my post that I did those 2 things already.

Comment: Did you do it in the right firewall profile? I have done it a few times with no issues. The only way to share an entire drive is using the admin share (i.e. F$). You should just share a folder that is in the root of the drive.

Comment: What is admin share?

Comment: your \\computername\c$ gives you access to the C drive of that computer. You have to use a login that is considered Administrator on that computer, or use the Administrator login for that computer.

Comment: It is a hidden share denoted by the $ at the end of the share and it doesn't show up when browsing to the computer, you have to know the full path. You can see a list of the default admin shares on the computer by going to Computer Management and viewing the shares.